# JavaScript Arrow Function to add values from an array when another array equals x

Tags: javascript, function, loops, foreach

I have some very clunky code that includes 2 for loops with if statements. They're pretty simple but I'm not getting the expected result when attempting to set the result toFixed(2). i'm trying to refactor it using arrow functions but I'm not finding anything specific to comparing 2 arrays and holding the value of one array when the same index of a 2nd array = "other fee". In total, I have 4 arrays. the first for loop looks for the feeAmts from that array and will hold the value when the feeCategory = Other Fee then it adds them.  The 2nd for loop does the same thing for override fees and categories.

I guess there's really 2 questions here.

1. Can this be done using arrow functions?
2. If not, how can I get the existing code to return the expected value with `toFixed(2)`. This code is currently only returning undefined.

```js
function main(feeAmts, feeCategory, ovrFeeAmts, ovrFeeCategory) {
  let result = 0.00;
  let tmpTotalOne = 0;
  let tmpTotalTwo = 0;
  const otherFee = "OTHER FEE";
  let ndx;

  for (ndx = 0; ndx < feeAmts.length; ndx += 1) {
    if (feeCategory[ndx].toUpperCase() === otherFee) {
      tmpTotalOne += feeAmts[ndx];
    }
  }

  for (ndx = 0; ndx < ovrFeeAmts.length; ndx += 1) {
    if (ovrFeeCategory[ndx].toUpperCase() === otherFee) {
      tmpTotalTwo += ovrFeeAmts[ndx];
    }
  }

  let ttl = (tmpTotalOne + tmpTotalTwo);
  result = (ttl.toFixed(2));
}

var result = main("_feeAmts", "_feeCategory", "_ovrFeeAmts", "_ovrFeeCategor");
const _feeAmts = [_feeAmtOne, _feeAmtTwo, _feeAmtThree, _feeAmtFour, _feeAmtFive,
  _feeAmtSix, _feeAmtSeven, _feeAmtEight, _feeAmtNine, _feeAmtTen, _feeAmtEleven,
  _feeAmtTwelve, _feeAmtThirteen, _feeAmtFrteen
];
const _feeCategory = ["_feeCategoryOne", "_feeCategoryTwo", "_feeCategoryThree",
  "_feeCategoryFour", "_feeCategoryFive", "_feeCategorySix", "_feeCategorySeven",
  "_feeCategoryEight", "_feeCategoryNine", "_feeCategoryTen", "_feeCategoryEleven",
  "_feeCategoryTwelve", "_feeCategoryThirteen", "_feeCategoryFrteen"
];
const _ovrFeeAmts = [_ovrFeeAmtOne, _ovrFeeAmtTwo, _ovrFeeAmtThree, _ovrFeeAmtFour,
  _ovrFeeAmtFive
];
const _ovrFeeCategory = ["_ovrFeeCategoryOne", "_ovrFeeCategoryTwo",
  "_ovrFeeCategoryThree", "_ovrFeeCategoryFour", "_ovrFeeCategoryFive"
];
```

Comment: for 1) of course you can - it's trivial to rewrite a "normal" function as an arrow function, and vice versa since, provided `this` isn't involved (and it isn't in your function), it's purely a syntactic change. As for 2), I haven't looked at your function in detail but I suspect it's because you're calling `main` with strings as arguments inside of your actual array variables.

Comment: I think you're confusing concepts. I think you're really asking if you can replace the loops with functions like `filter()` or `reduce()`, is that right? Arrow functions are just a shorter way of writing the callback functions when you use these.

Comment: But as @RobinZigmond said, the main problem you have is you're using strings where you should have variables. Also, you can't refer to `_feeAmts` and `_feeCategories` before you assign them, so the call to `main()` needs to be at the end.

Comment: I should have mentioned that this code runs as raw JavaScript that gets injected into a low code web application.  We create the variable names and the input value for each one is pulled from a group and field out of their database.  I could definitely be getting confused but my thought was to simplify the code even if it's only a syntactic change.  I've used arrow functions with .filter(), .reduce(), .some(), .include() etc but I haven't used them where I'm comparing the index of one array and pulling the value at the same index of another array if the first array matches the passed argument.

Comment: Why would comparing indexes make any difference when using an arrow function? The array index is passed as the second argument to the function when you use any of those functions that loop over an array. So `array.filter((element, ndx) => { ... })`

Comment: Sorry, I just don't have a great grasp on all of while learning it through this backwards method in this application. I just like the code to look clean but understandable but still minimal.  I'm just trying to figure out how to make this work: if feeAmountOne: 10 AND feeCategoryOne: "Other Fee" and ovrFeeAmtOne: 10 AND overFeeCategoryOne: "Other Fee" result = "20.00"; Loop through all feeAmounts and feeCategories and add them together if the equivalent feeCategory index = "Other Fee". If there's a feeAmount value at index[3] and feeCategory index[3] is "race car" then don't add it to the sum.

Comment: "OTHER FEE" doesn't appear in your `_feeCategory` array at all.  What are all these weird strings doing where there should be data?

Comment: Only for use inside the application.  When I'm testing in VS Code I have all of those commented out and I'm exporting main to an app.js file where there are assertions.  A single assertion would include a value or "".  Like this: Assert.strictEqual(otherFee([ 10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ["Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee"], [20.1, 20.2, 20.3, 20.4, 20.5], ["Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee", "Other Fee"]), "131.50");

Comment: Geez.  I was getting undefined because the return value wasn't defined.  I added return result; after the result = (ttl.toFixed(2)); and it's working.  I would still like to understand how I could write this with arrow functions.  Probably more reading but thank you for all of your quick responses and guidance! Feel free to post a sample arrow function performing the same operations just so I can see how it's supposed to be written.